# Two files present on CVS server per commit. How can we achieve this?

Tags: version-control, cvs, release-management

So I'm a beginning CVS administrator (Release Management). Yes, the client's still hooked up with CVS in 2016.
So i know for a fact, that when you commit a file in cvs (say, a.txt) it creates a history file called a.txt,v.
But on the server in CVSROOT, I've seen that there are many (30-35 instances atleast) instances where there are two files b.txt and b.txt,v

b.txt,v is your standard CVS history file and b.txt always displays just the latest version of the file (the checked out version).
For example, if i update (and commit) a file c.txt from "1234" to "12345" both c.txt and c.txt,v gets updated automatically.
Before update, c.txt used to read "1234", and automatically after update it displays the latest version "12345".

Mind you, This is on the CVS server and not on the checked out code. And the c.txt file is maintained automatically by CVS.

I need to add files in CVSROOT, but when I commit I'm only able to get history file and not the second one.
Can somebody explain how this can be achieved? That on commit of a file, two file gets created on the CVS server (c.txt and c.txt,v) where the former always displays the latest version of the file? 
Have tried searching, but haven't found any such concept.
Can someone please guide me in the correct direction?

Comment: If one of the answers is the correct answer to your question, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark. This gives the answerer points and StackOverflow is points- and reputation-based. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have almost everything you need to understand this already described above.

For normal server-side files in a CVS repository, only the RCS (`,v`) files are present on the filesystem of the server. But in the special CVSROOT module, the CVS server has checked-out copies of all of the files as the server needs these to run. Because CVS is kind of backwards and dumb, it stores these checked-out versions directly in the same server-repository directory as the normal server-side CVSROOT ,v files.

If you want to modify one, you just `cvs co CVSROOT` and you get a regular cvs workspace with the latest versions of the files in CVSROOT. This is exactly the same as if one of the devs were to `cvs co <module>` and get a copy of the code. Then you modify the server-configuration file and `cvs commit <filename>` and it will be committed into CVSROOT and additionally on the server that latest copy will be checked out so the server will start using it immediately.

Comment: But i have never had the need to add a new script to CVSROOT. Now I do.
If I'm doing a normal commit in the CVSROOT, I'm only getting the RCS file.
How do I get that second checked-out version of the script, which I'm trying to add?